# Passing data among different HTML pages

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm new to PHP and very lost.

I'm working with HTML5, CSS3, jQuery and Bootstrap 4.

I have a total of 4 HTML pages on my website. In the first page there are 4 squares with text (let's say A, B, C and D), user selects one of those squares and then presses the "Next" button. On click of this "next" user is taken to page 2 but this page needs to be updated according to user's selection in page 1 (A, B, C or D). And similarly data from page 2 and page 1 needs to be taken to page 3.

I read about doing it via URLs, AJAX, PHP sessions and a few more things, but since I'm new at this I'm very confused.

Please guide as to how can I pass data among different pages?

EDIT: I've not used forms.

Comment: Create 4 sections with a page itself. One load section 1 make visible and all other 3 section make as hidden using `display none`. When clicking Next on step1 make all blocks hidden and go to section 2 by making it visible. Proceed like this to the 4th block. On eact Next click save data to session using `AJAX`. You can use this session to show data in case of a refresh

Comment: there are lot of ways to do things , in javascript as well as in sessions. You can store in localstorage too.

Comment: you can use cookies but local storages allows you much more spaces and will be sent back to server when you request pages.

Comment: @Ajith Thank you for your response, I had already coded and I had only one next button, hence your approach is different from mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with use of `localstorage`

*First Page: (first.html)*

```
localStorage.setItem("square_first", "A");
```

*Second Page: (second.html)*

```
localStorage.getItem("square_first");
```

Answer (score 2):

There method depends on the purpose, this is one of the fundamental concepts and components in web development.

1. **If you want to store or record your users interaction** (for e-commerce, or social networking purposes) you will need the data to be passed to the server at some point (maybe after using a local storage object), there are 2 commonly used mechanisms PHP gives us to pass data from the client side to server side: $_GET & $_POST through a HTML from, and these can persist used cookies or sessions
2. **If the data passed between pages is never going to provide any purpose for the site's function**, then the local storage object may be used, the local storage object is particularly useful when large amounts of data may be stored on the users client, rather than fetching this expensive resource per request, to enhance user experience and minimise server load

Comment: Thanks! For my code, localstorage approach worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use local storage following example will definitely help you.

on HTML page 1:

```
window.onload = function() {
   var sqa = prompt("square: ","A");
   localStorage.setItem("SQA",sqa);
}
```

On HTML page 2:

```
window.onload = alert(localStorage.getItem("SQA"));
```

You can use cookies but storage is better option as page request is not sent to server.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Passing data among different HTML pages</title>

        <script
            src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <div>
            <p>Section-A</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
            </p>
            <input type="hidden" name="dataA" id="dataA" value="sample data A"/>
            <button class="send_data" value="A">Next</button>
        </div>

        <div>
            <p>Section-B</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
            </p>
            <input type="hidden" name="dataB" id="dataB" value="sample data B"/>
            <button class="send_data" value="B">Next</button>
        </div>

        <div>
            <p>Section-C</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
            </p>
            <input type="hidden" name="dataC" id="dataC" value="sample data C"/>
            <button class="send_data" value="C">Next</button>
        </div>

        <div>
            <p>Section-D</p>

            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
            </p>
            <input type="hidden" name="dataD" id="dataD" value="sample data D"/>
            <button class="send_data" value="D">Next</button>
        </div>


    </body>
</html>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
     
        $(".send_data").click(function(event){
      
            var url="";
            let sec = $(this).prop("value");
            let data = $('#data'+sec).val();

            if (sec=="A"){
                url = 'demoA.html';
            } else if (sec=="B"){
                url = 'demoA.html';
            }
            else if (sec=="C"){
                url = 'demoA.html';
            }
            else if (sec=="D"){
                url = 'demoA.html';
            }

            var form = $('<form action="' + url + '" method="post">' +
                '<input type="text" name="data" value="'+data+'" />' +
                '</form>');
            $('body').append(form);
            form.submit();

        });
      
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Please explain your solution instead of just giving some code

Comment: In the HTML there are four divs and on each div there is a button with the class, value and some demo data (need to be parsed on other page). 
In the jquery Function, when the user clicks on a button, the value of the clicked button is parced in the function, 

let sec = $(this).prop("value");
let data = $('#data'+sec).val(); // conatating ID to get the clicked button's parent Div data,

Comment: This will help you if you want the separate links to be rediected 

if (sec=="A"){
url = 'demoA.html';
} else if (sec=="B"){
url = 'demoB.html';
}The below code is pasing the data on the desired url uding form append 

var form = $('<form action="' + url + '" method="post">' +
  '<input type="text" name="data" value="'+data+'" />' +
  '</form>');
$('body').append(form);
form.submit();

Comment: Hi @fahadpatel, I appreciate your response, but I've not coded the layout as a form, hence I was looking for something without the use of forms, sorry, I forgot to mention that in my question.

Comment: @fahadpatel hey, I've already gotten the solution, thank you for your time! :)